# Is it possible to process string from starting for DP solution

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying out [longest palindromic subsequence problem from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-subsequence/).

[One of the discussed solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-subsequence/discuss/1468396/C%2B%2BPython-2-solutions%3A-Top-down-DP-Bottom-up-DP-O(N)-Space-Clean-and-Concise) is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindromeSubseq(self, s: str) -> int:
        n = len(s)
        dp = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
        for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
            dp[i][i] = 1
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                if s[i] == s[j]:
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j - 1] + 2
                else:
                    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i + 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])
        return dp[0][n - 1]
```

So it starts from end of the string:

[image]

I was guessing if it is possible to begin from the starting of the string. That is if its possible to have loops something like this:

```
         for i in range(0, n):
            for j in range(i+1, n): 
                # ...
```

But `dp[i + 1]` wont be calculated for any given iteration of `i` and we need dp[i+1] for evaluating

- `dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j - 1] + 2` and
- `dp[i][j] = max(dp[i + 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])`

Is it possible to change these two updates to `dp` (and hence come up with new recurrence relation) in some way to make it possible to begin from the starting of the string or starting from the end of the string is the only way possible !? (I was not able to come up with any recurrence solution / index adjustments to make it possible. So I have started to believe that its indeed not possible. But I wanted to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

The first hint that you can do this from the beginning is that let's say you're given a string 'baabbcc' that this logic gets the answer for, the same logic will work for the reversed string as well ('ccbbaab').

The more robust reasoning for this can be derived from what `dp[i][j]` represents. The value represents the **Longest Palindromic Subsequence between i and j inclusive**. We calculate this `dp` array using two pointers, say `i` and `j`.

We iterate over all possible values of `i` and `j`, and if `s[i] == s[j]` then we know that the answer from `i` to `j` will be equal to the answer for `i+1` to `j-1` + 2 because we can take the answer from `i+1` to  `j-1` and add `s[i]` and `s[j]` to the beginning and end of that. I hope this is clear from the code you provided.

What that means is that to calculate `dp[i][j]`, you need `dp[i+1][j-1]`.

The code you have provided does this by starting the `i` pointer from the ending and for every `i`, it loops from `j = i` till `j = n-1`. This means that `i+1` is reached before `i` and `j-1` is reached before `j`.

However, you can achieve the same effect starting from the beginning. This time, start by moving the `j` pointer from the beginning, and for every `j`, move the `i` pointer backward from `i = j` till `i = 0`. This ensures that `j-1` is reached before `j` and `i+1` is reached before `i`, which is what we're looking for.

The final code would look something like this (Which I've submitted and gotten accepted):

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindromeSubseq(self, s: str) -> int:
        n = len(s)
        dp = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
        for j in range(0, n):
            dp[j][j] = 1
            for i in range(j-1, -1, -1):
                if s[i] == s[j]:
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j - 1] + 2
                else:
                    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i + 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])
        return dp[0][n - 1]
```